# CodeIgniter loggin in

Tags: php, codeigniter, logging

Okay so in my database i have table called 'users' with email, pw and some other fields. Registration works. But i can't make loggin in.

Controller view:

```
public function index()
{   

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email2', 'Email', 'trim|required|valid_email');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('pw2', 'Hasło', 'trim|required|md5');

    $this->load->view('header_view');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE)
    {
        $this->load->view('account_view');
    }
    else
    {
        $email = $this->input->post('email2');
        $password = $this->input->post('pw2');
        $this->load->model('login_model');

        if($user = $this->login_model->login_user($email, $password))
        {
            $this->session->set_userdata('user_id', $user['id']);
            redirect('home');
        }
        else
        {
            redirect('account');
}
```

Model view:
    class login_model extends CI_Model
    {
        public $table = 'users';

```
    public function login_user($email, $pw)
    { 
        return $this->db->where(array('email' => $email, 'pw' => $pw))->get($this->table)->row_array();     
    }
```

View:

```
<p>
    <?php echo form_error('email2'); ?>
    <input type="text" id="email2" name="email2" value="<?php echo set_value('email2'); ?>" />
    <label for="email2">Email</label>
</p>
<p>
    <?php echo form_error('pw2'); ?>
    <input type="password" id="pw2" name="pw2" />
    <label for="pw2">Hasło</label>
</p>
<p>
    <input type="submit" value="Zaloguj" />
</p>
<?php echo form_close(); ?>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your controller:

```
public function index()
{   

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email2', 'Email', 'trim|required|valid_email');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('pw2', 'Hasło', 'trim|required|md5');

    $this->load->view('header_view');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE)
    {
        $this->load->view('account_view');
    }
    else
    {
            redirect('home','refresh'); 
    }


 function check_database($password)
 {
   //Field validation succeeded.  Validate against database
   $username = $this->input->post('email2');

   //query the database
   $result = $this->user->login($email2, $password);

   if($result)
   {
     $sess_array = array();
     foreach($result as $row)
     {
       $sess_array = array(
         'id' => $row->id,
         'email2' => $row->email2
       );
       $this->session->set_userdata('logged_in', $sess_array);
     }
     return TRUE;
   }
   else
   {
     $this->form_validation->set_message('check_database', 'Invalid username or password');
     return false;
   }
 }
```

In your model:

```
Class User extends CI_Model
{
 function login($username, $password)
 {
   $this -> db -> select('id, email, pw');
   $this -> db -> from('users');
   $this -> db -> where('email', $email2);
   $this -> db -> where('pw', MD5($password));
   $this -> db -> limit(1);

   $query = $this -> db -> get();

   if($query -> num_rows() == 1)
   {
     return $query->result();
   }
   else
   {
     return false;
   }
 }
}
```